# Autobiographer Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

To get this badge we have to complete all user profile fields. I have completed all profile. Why I'm not getting it? What all fields are their to to filled? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[Autobiographer Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57865/didnt-get-the-autobiographer-badge) - they say you need the *website* field also filled in (which I don't see on your bio). Try "n/a" if you don't have one (or if that doesn't work, microsoft.com. :)